# Probability of k-clique in a random graph

Tags: probability-theory, clique, random-graphs

I need to find the order of the minimum k = k(n) such that the probability of having at least 1 k-clique in a random graph $G(n, \frac{1}{2}$) is $\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n})$.
$X_k$ is the random variable which count the number of k-cliques in a random graph.
I already know $E[X_k] = \binom{n}{k}(\frac{1}{2})^{\binom{k}{2}}$.
I don't know exactly how to find the exact value of k.
I know $P[X_k \geq 1] \leq E[X_k]$ for Markov inequality but I'm not sure that this is helpful.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The value is $2\log_2 n - 2\log_2\log_2 n + O(1)$.

Let $k_0$ be the maximal value such that the expected number of cliques of size $k_0$ is at least 1. A boring calculation shows that $k_0 = 2\log_2 n - 2\log_2\log_2 n + O(1)$. It is a classical result that with high probability, $G(n,1/2)$ contains a $(k_0-1)$-clique. This implies that $k > k_0-1$. On the other hand, it is known that the expected number of cliques of size $k_0+1+C$ is $O((\log n/n)^C)$ for any constant $C$ (this is because the expected number of cliques drops by $\Theta(\log n/n)$ near $k_0$). This shows that $k \leq k_0+3$. We conclude that $k_0 \leq k \leq k_0+3$.

You can probably decrease the length of this interval by 1, following the proof of the classical result which shows concentration of the clique number of *two* values rather than *three*.

Comment: Could you please clarify the calculation for $k_0$? And what is that classical result you mentioned?

Comment: I skipped the calculation since it's very tiring. You can find the details in *Random graphs* by Frieze and Karonski.

Comment: I couldn't find it, could you please just tell me the idea behind it?

Comment: It's just a calculation. You have to push through it. See Lemma 9.1 [here](http://cs.technion.ac.il/~yuvalfi/2017-random-graphs/LectureNotes.pdf).